# Sum of possibilities of values for "a"

Tags: functions

The sum of all different values of "a" for which the equation 4a[X]^2 = a+12 has solutions in [1, infinity) is?
[K] denotes Greatest integer function
I fail to understand what concept I should start with I need help on it.

Comment: What did you try on this question?

Comment: I tried to separate out [x] and a and then analyse values of a for which I get [X] in the given set but I then am not able to do more on it.

Comment: Also, I presume $a$ is an integer, and you get a Diophantine equation.

Comment: No, this question is not just for integer $a$, and is in fact non-trivial. The down vote was unjustified in my opinion, since the sum over possible $a$ is actually quite hard

Comment: (By hard I mean it requires at least some thought - and if you have never seen an infinite series then it would be difficult)

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given integer $x\ge1$, we find $a={12\over 4x^2-1}$ is the only possible $a$, and this always exists. Hence we are trying to evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{12\over4n^2-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{12\over(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{6\over(2n-1)}-{6\over(2n+1)}$$ This is a telescoping sum, and it is also convergent (we can check the partial sums are all less than 6, and are increasing), hence we find that the sum is 6.